# Group by in Influx DB like MySql

Tags: influxdb

I am very new to Influx DB and curious, how does Group By Works. For e.g. how can I execute following MySql Query in InfluxDb:

select mean(cputime), vm from CPU group by vm;

Comment: What have you tried and what problem are you having.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please remember: this is NOT a relational database, the InfluxQL is NOT SQL (even though looking so familiar).

In particular, here:

1) You won't be to get aggregate and non-aggregate values in the meantime (whatever that "non" is, field or tag). Yes, even with grouping.

2) Effectively, you can group only by tags (+ special kind of grouping by time intervals)

So, considering "vm" is a tag in your query - it is not legit.

While that

```
select mean(cputime) from CPU group by vm
```

is, but I'd rather strongly discourage you and anyone of not having time restrictions on their queries: aside of being quite meaningless, as the timeseries get grown, it's gonna slow everything down dramatically.

So something like this:

```
select mean(cputime) from CPU where time > now() - 15m group by vm
```

or even this:

```
select mean(cputime) from CPU where time > now() - 90m group by time(15m), vm
```

gonna be way better.